# Blinking characters on Intel 8086

Tags: vga, video-card

I'm working on drawing some shapes directly using the graphics card without interrupts for Intel 8086 (TASM) and I read that the 7th bit in the byte responsible for background and foreground colours can make the characters blink.

How can I set it, though, while the colours themselves are indexed 0-15 and I have only 1 byte? I mean: I can set the colour byte to `1eh` so that I have a yellow char on blue background. How can I squeeze the information about the desired blinking in there?

Comment: If you are drawing some shapes, the video adapter must be in graphic mode. But the text rasterization can occur only in text mode. Both modes can't be turned on at the same time. Either you have missed something in this description or you have been trying something impossible.

Comment: Regardless of the CPU you are using or the language you are writing, the answer to this question will always be the same, for all VGA devices. Because of that, this question is *not* related with x86 or with assembly, hence those tags are not valid here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I set [the 7th bit], though, while the colours themselves are indexed 0-15 and I have only 1 byte?

It's actually bit 7, not the 7th bit (those two are not the same). The mask for bit 7 is `80h` (or 128 decimal), so to set a green color with blinking on you'd use an attribute of `82h`, for blinking magenta it would be `85h`, and so on.